# Ignore ThreadAbortException when logging exceptions

Tags: asp.net, logging, exception

What's the correct way of ignoring ThreadAbortException when logging exceptions?

Is it safe to just catch it in an empty catch block to make it disappear?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to stop a `ThreadAbortException` propogating further up the call stack, you can call `Thread.ResetAbort`. So try something like:

```
try
{
  // some code
}
catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
{
  // do some logging
  Thread.ResetAbort();
}
```

As for "correct" - that depends on your usage scenario. I'd generally be cautious about catching these unless you understand exactly why it has been raised. In escence it is a *"stop now, quickly, and drop what you are doing"* signal. Resetting it and going on to do further processing should be done with caution.

Comment: I would not recommend this!
It will not only prevent the ThreadAbortException from logging it will discard it completely. This can have significant unwanted side effects like Application Appartments that never terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Employ two `catch` blocks: one for `ThreadAbortException` and one for the rest, for example:

```
void MainLoop()
{   bool workdone;
    try
    {   while( IsWorking ) // cross-thread volatile variable
        {   workdone = Process();
            if( !workdone )
            {   Thread.Sleep( 500 );  }
        }
    }
    catch( ThreadAbortException )
    {   // Forced termination. Exit silently.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {   LogError( e );  }
}
```

Comment: @Marcel, I have seen your proposed extension of my anser, but cannot say whether they are correct on not. If you think they are important, I suggest that you post them in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

<del>It is safe to catch it in a separate catch block. As an alternative you can catch all Exceptions and then check if a given Exception `e is ThreadAbortException`</del>

I leave this post just because of the comments. Obviously, I was not knowing much about that exception.

Comment: ThreadAbortExceptions have some unique behavior in the way they interact with try/catch blocks: in some (all?) circumstances, they will automatically be re-thrown from the catch block, so you may not be able to completely "swallow" the exception as you would other types.

I admit, I don't fully understand the nuances of this behavior.  This thread might be able to give you more insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830389/whats-the-deal-with-the-hidden-throw-when-catching-a-threadabortexception

Comment: It seems I managed to "swallow" the Exception, or at least it's not caught again in the next "catch (Exception)" block that writes a log entry, which is what I wanted to achieve. Just wondering if that's a safe way to do it, and it doesn't break anything else (it all seems to be working fine, but with the mad ASP.NET lifecycle, you never know...)

Answer (score 0):

With newer .NET versions ignoring an exception can be simplified to

```
try
{   // ...
}
catch (Exception e) when (!(e is ThreadAbortException))
{   LogError( e );
}
```

---

But this might still not be enough. **Some libraries tend to wrap all exceptions with their own exception.** In this case it could happen that the `ThreadAbortExceptiononly` appears as `InnerException`. I would not call it best practice to wrap a `ThreadAbortException` but it is real world.

To come around this I recommend an extension:

```
public static bool IsThreadAbort(this Exception ex)
{
    while (ex != null)
    {
        if (ex is ThreadAbortException)
            return true;
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can check with:

```
catch (Exception e) when (!e.IsThreadAbort())
{   LogError( e );
}
```

Comment: Performant? Call on every exception?

Comment: Comparing to the exception itself and the logging (typically with function name and/or call stack) the performance impact is negligible.